# characterizing the singularity for a geometric flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a complete Riemannian manifold and let $\Gamma_0$ be a closed hypersurface in $M$. Let $(x^n,x')$ denote the normal coordinate system on $M$ about $\Gamma_0$ with $x^n>0$ inside $\Gamma_0$ and $x^n<0$ outside $\Gamma_0$. Now let $\Gamma_t= \{x^n=t\}$. Clearly, there is a maximal $t_0$ for which $\Gamma_t$ is smoothly defined for all $t<t_0$. My question is what can be said about $\Gamma_{t_0}$. Is this a reasonable hypersurface? say a Lipschitz hypersurface or a smooth hypersurface with some corners, etc.

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing, because the level sets of a coordinate function are regular. Do you mean $\Gamma_t = \{ p \in M \mid d(p,\Gamma_0) = t \}$? Certainly the critical $\Gamma_{t_0}$ can contain lower-dimensional portions, of any codimension. Even that aside, I'm a bit skeptical, depending on what you mean by 'reasonable'. It seems to that in $\mathbf{R}^2$ you can get several curves meeting at a point or curves with cusps, for example.